# Animated GIF images getting pixelated when saving gif image with Python Image Library(PIL)

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, python-imaging-library, animated-gif, hug

I am trying to create an image upload utility in [Hug](https://hugapi.github.io/hug/) / python and wanted to save images and gifs. But on uploading some of the gif images, the gif images seem to be a lot pixelated. Given below is the code snippet that I am using in the upload utility.

```py
 image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file))
 frames = [frame.copy() for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image)]
 image.save(media_location, save_all=True, append_images=frames)
```

- **The original GIF** :

  [via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/jointeamalpha-reaction-and-wacuipKofK23LEdi1m)

  [image]



  **The uploaded GIF** 


  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

The workaround can be not passing the animated images with PIL and directly storing it with a `context manager`.

```py
    if image.is_animated:
        with open(media_location, 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(byte_stream)
```